# how to anchor a view in front of the toolbar?

Tags: java, android

how to anchor a view in front of the toolbar?
please help me like this.
indeed I wish to place this half circle above the toolbar as shown below

[image]

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: you need to user CoordinatorLayout or ConstraintsLayout

Comment: ConstraintsLayout????

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffaa">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar">

 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/semicircle"
    android:layout_marginTop="-170dp"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

output:

[image]

Keep `layout_marginTop` for image view as per your convenience

Comment: png image of a semi circle